# React warning render [antd: Cascader] Not found `value` in `options`

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am exploring https://stackblitz.com/run components-cascader-demo-lazy in Ant. Now in my case I am trying to set the options dynamically from REST Api. This is my code snippet

```
state = {
domains: [] ,
};
componentWillMount() {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/domains')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then((data) => {
          for (const [_, value] of data.entries()) {
      domains.push({"value":value.id.toString(),"label":value.name,"isLeaf":false,})
              }
        console.log(domains)
  this.setState({ domains: data })
})
.catch(console.log)
};
 render() {
   console.log(this.state.domains)
   return (
   <Cascader
    options={this.state.domains}
    loadData={this.loadData}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    changeOnSelect
  />
 );
}
```

Even though I am able to console the expected json data (in expected ant-cascade format) , still getting the error `render [antd: Cascader] Not found`value`in`options`.`. I am very new in React World , and help here is appreciated .

Comment: can u paste domains array after fetching. Cascader couldn’t get value element which is expected.

Comment: @ByrisettiHemanth my bad `this.setState({ domains: data })` this should be `this.setState({ domains: domains })`.

Comment: Only render Cascader after this.state.domains.length > 0.